# i create an algorithm and when i try to print it, bufferedWriter create an empty file

Tags: java

i made an algorithm to do a calculus. it works well but bufferedWriter creates an empty file. I tried every kind of solutions, but every time it creates an empty file. i need the file as txt. how to fix it?

to help you reading my code:

addressCalc() is a function that open a txt and upload in an hashmap the data

uniqueAddress() is a function that calculate how many unique address there are in my data

nftNumbers() is a function that calculate how many nfts has each address

calculus() is the function that i need to print in a txt the final result

```
package calculator.v2;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class AlgorithmV2 {
    
    HashMap <Integer, String> listAddress;
    HashMap <Integer, String> totalAddress;
    HashMap <String, String> uniqueAddress;
    HashMap <Integer, String> orderAddress;
    HashMap <String, Float> nfts;
    int totalNfts = 33;
    float cifra;
    String lucifer, astaroth, beelzebup;

    public AlgorithmV2() {
        super();
        
        listAddress = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        totalAddress = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        uniqueAddress = new HashMap<String, String>();
        orderAddress = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        nfts = new HashMap<String, Float>();
        addressCalc();
        uniqueAddress();
        nftNumbers();
        calculus();
    }
    
    
    public float getCifra() {
        return cifra;
    }

    public void setCifra(float cifra) {
        this.cifra = cifra;
    }


    public HashMap<Integer, String> getTotalAddress() {
        return totalAddress;
    }

    public void setTotalAddress(HashMap<Integer, String> totalAddress) {
        this.totalAddress = totalAddress;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getUniqueAddress() {
        return uniqueAddress;
    }

    public void setUniqueAddress(HashMap<String, String> uniqueAddress) {
        this.uniqueAddress = uniqueAddress;
    }

    public HashMap<Integer, String> getOrderAddress() {
        return orderAddress;
    }

    public void setOrderAddress(HashMap<Integer, String> orderAddress) {
        this.orderAddress = orderAddress;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Float> getNfts() {
        return nfts;
    }

    public void setNfts(HashMap<String, Float> nfts) {
        this.nfts = nfts;
    }

    public int getTotalNfts() {
        return totalNfts;
    }

    public void setTotalNfts(int totalNfts) {
        this.totalNfts = totalNfts;
    }



    public float addressCalc() {
        
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("src\\calculator\\data\\snapshot.txt");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String line;
            Pattern addressPattern = Pattern.compile("stars+[A-Za-z0-9]+");
            int i = 0;

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                Matcher address = addressPattern.matcher(line);
            
                if(address.find()) {
                        listAddress.put(i, address.group(0));
                        i++;
                }
            }

            reader.close();

            return 1;   

        }    catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
    }
    
    public void uniqueAddress(){
        
        int temp = 0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < listAddress.size(); i++) {
            
            if(uniqueAddress.get(listAddress.get(i)) == null) {
                uniqueAddress.put(listAddress.get(i), listAddress.get(i));
                orderAddress.put(temp, listAddress.get(i));
                temp++;
            }
        }       
    }
    
    public void nftNumbers() {

        try {
            
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("src\\calculator\\data\\data.txt");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
            cifra = Float.parseFloat(bufferedReader.readLine());
            lucifer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            beelzebup = bufferedReader.readLine();
            astaroth = bufferedReader.readLine();
            
            reader.close();
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        
        float temp = 0;
        int n;
        
        for(int i=0; i < uniqueAddress.size(); i++) {
            
            for(int j=0; j < listAddress.size(); j++) {
                
                if(uniqueAddress.get(orderAddress.get(i)).equals(listAddress.get(j))) {
                    
                    temp++;
                }
            }
                        
            if(temp >= 6) {

                temp = temp + temp/3;                       
            }
            
            if(astaroth.equals(uniqueAddress.get(orderAddress.get(i))) || lucifer.equals(uniqueAddress.get(orderAddress.get(i))) || beelzebup.equals(uniqueAddress.get(orderAddress.get(i)))) {

                temp += 11;
            }
            
            
            n = (int) temp;
            totalNfts += n;
        
            nfts.put(uniqueAddress.get(orderAddress.get(i)), temp);
            
            temp = 0;
            
        }
    }

    public void calculus() {
        
        float temp = (float) 0;

          
          try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("rewards.txt", true)){

              BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
              
                for(int i = 0; i < orderAddress.size(); i++) {

                    temp = nfts.get(orderAddress.get(i))/totalNfts*cifra;
                    System.out.println(orderAddress.get(i)+","+temp);
                    bw.write(orderAddress.get(i)+","+temp);
                    temp = 0;
                }
                
                bw.close();
          }
            catch(IOException e){
              // handle the exception
        }
    }
}``
```

Comment: Never catch an exception without handle it. Atleast log it

Comment: Why do you feel anything should get written? At a glance, it should write to the file but there isn't any guarantee that "orderAddress" has anything it in. Of course as mentioned elsewhere ... handle your exception.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your code produces an exception before the file could be written. You could try the following to narrow down the problem (if you are not comfortable with using a debugger):

```
public void calculus() {
    
      float temp = (float) 0;

      String baseDir = "C:/Users/..../folder";
      try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(baseDir + "rewards.txt", true)){

          BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

          // check if this string will be present in 
          // your file
          bw.write("Test");

          // this will force the BufferedWriter to 
          // write to the file immediately
                bw.flush();

          System.out.println("orderAddress.size() = " + orderAddress.size());
          for(int i = 0; i < orderAddress.size(); i++) {

                temp = nfts.get(orderAddress.get(i))/totalNfts*cifra;
                System.out.println(orderAddress.get(i)+","+temp);
                bw.write(orderAddress.get(i)+","+temp);
                temp = 0;

                // this will force the BufferedWriter to 
                // write to the file immediately
                bw.flush();
          }
            
          bw.close();
      }
      catch(IOException e){
          // 1
          System.err.println(e);
          // 2
          throw new RuntimeException("IOException occurred" +
                " while trying to write to file.", e);
    }
}
```

I added some lines...

First, I added a new variable `baseDir` where you can set the path to the folder in which the file should be created.

`bw.write("Test");` checks if "Test" will appear in your file. Then I added `bw.flush();` twice. This force the `BufferedWriter` to immediately write to the file. If an exception occurred in the for-loop, your file will still contain the last *working* execution.

In the catch-block you should handle your exception in some way. I provided you with two of many other possibilities:

1. If you want your program to continue when an exception occurs, you can just print the exception to the console, so you would still be aware of it.
2. If you want your program to stop when an exception occurs, you can throw a RuntimeException

Comment: Test appears, but the loop doesn't work

Comment: Do you get an error / exception?

Comment: I added `System.out.println("orderAddress.size() = " + orderAddress.size());` before the for-loop. What is the output of this statement? And are you getting exceptions?

Comment: i don't get any exception. size() is correct (239 addresses)

Comment: if i use System.out.println(orderAddress.get(i)+","+temp); inside the loop, it prints the correct results

Comment: i think the problem is due to a previous statement, but printwriter is the first occurrence in the program

Comment: The only plausible reason I can find for an empty result file is `totalNfts == 0`. But I thought that must throw an exception. If you checked that this is not the case, I cannot help any further than to recommend you to use a debugger to observe the values and the behavior live. Which IDE do you use?

Comment: TotalNfts != 0. I can print the correct result by println(). I use eclipse

Comment: I adapted my answer. I assume that the file was always created with the path C:/rewards.txt (on windows systems) and you where maybe looking at another file all the time. Please set the path to a folder and open that folder. Before execution, move any other rewards.txt - file to the recycling bin.

Comment: It's not another file because the timestamp is the same as the execution

Comment: Then I'm at my wits end with the provided information....Did you already use the debugger in Eclipse?

Comment: yep, i don't find any bug

Comment: please let me know if you fixed your problem. I'm very curious what let your code fail...